# How to add delimiter while writing .csv file using openCSV

Tags: java

I'm writing a csv file in java and i want to write csv file with '|' as delimiter. How can i do in my code.

## This is my Java code:

```
public void createCsv(User user) {
    
    try( FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(CSV_FILE_NAME,true);
            CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(writer,
                    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_SEPARATOR,
                    CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
                    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,
                    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END);
            
            CSVReader reader = new CSVReader(new FileReader(CSV_FILE_NAME));){
        
        if(reader.readNext() !=null) {
            csvWriter.writeNext(new String[]{user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName()});             
        }else {
            String[] headerRecord = {"First Name", "Last Name"};
            csvWriter.writeNext(headerRecord);

            csvWriter.writeNext(new String[]{user.getFirstName(), user.getLastName()});             
        }
        
        
        
    } catch (IOException e) {
        
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: The separator is the delimiter - don't use the default separator - use the `'|'` in there instead

Comment: http://opencsv.sourceforge.net/apidocs/com/opencsv/CSVWriter.html#CSVWriter(java.io.Writer,%20char,%20char,%20char,%20java.lang.String)

Comment: However, according to the JavaDocs, any constructor that sends more than the `Writer` is deprecated.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use this snippet for instantiating `CSVWriter`.

```
CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(writer,
                                    '|',
                                    CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER,
                                    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_ESCAPE_CHARACTER,
                                    CSVWriter.DEFAULT_LINE_END);
```

Answer (score 2):

Just pass the pipe character as the default separator.

```
CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(writer,'|');
```